# snowflake: ON_ERROR= CONTINUE FOR INSERT INTO, similary to COPY INTO

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have `on_error = 'continue;'` or `validation_mode = 'RETURN_100_ROWS'`  for `COPY INTO`

Similarly do we have the same option for `INERT INTO` also.

Answer (score 0):

Im afraid INSERT does not have any error detection mechanism as Copy Into. In Insert you are explicitly passing the values to a Table, hence you have the context of what values you are inserting as compared to Copy Into, where bulk load into table happens.